# Textview in dialog is cut off

Tags: android, textview

I put textview in dialog programmatically. A textview shows file path. But textview cuts off text if it goes out of dialog.

```
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1f);

TableLayout table = new TableLayout (context);
table.setLayoutParams(tableParams);

TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

TextView text = new TextView(context);
TextView textTitle = new TextView(context);

textTitle.setText("File path ");
text.setText(name);
text.setLines(1);
text.setSingleLine(true);
text.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
text.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

row.addView(textTitle);
row.addView(text);
table.addView(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code for you textview whitch shows path

```
textview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```